# How to fix `command not found: loads` error when starting up iTerm2 and zsh?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

I have a new Mac that I'm trying to set up iTerm2 and zsh. I'm no expert so keep that in mind when reading my question.

When I open iTerm2 it logs out a few lines ending in `command not found: loads`.
Why is it logging these lines?
What are these lines?
How can I fix the `command not found: loads` error?
How can I get iTerm to startup without logging these lines?

This is the log printed when starting up iTerm2:

```
COLORFGBG='7;0'
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
HOME=/Users/foo
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew
INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:15936235-F041-4706-8535-D695FB821AF0
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.19
LESS=-R
LOGNAME=foo
LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
LS_COLORS='di=1;36:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43'
MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man::
OLDPWD=/Users/foo
PAGER=less
PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
PWD=/Users/foo
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.dCNixhF/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.19
TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:15936235-F041-4706-8535
TMPDIR=/var/folders/p2/t222hg_j40b00gr/T/
USER=foo
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
ZSH=/Users/foo/.oh-my-zsh
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:15
/Users/foo/.zshrc:114: command not found: loads
```

Comment: You did not show the complete output, but from what you said, these are not _logs_, but _error messages_. Your zsh startup files try to run a command named _loads_, and this is not found by zsh. To debug this, it would indeed make sense to actually **log** your startup. Run a new login shell with `zsh -lx` and analytze the log to find which statement in your startup files cause the error.